# "The package java.sql is not accessible." in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, accessible

```java
package test;

import java.sql.*;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image]

in the above code. `import java.sql.*;` contain error that is `"The package java.sql is not accessible"`. Please help me to resolve this error. why java.sql is not accessible.

Comment: What is the version of JDK configured

Comment: 13.0.2 version of jdk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can see the `module-info.java` file in your screenshot, which means you use Java 9 and above. Please add the following in the `module-info.java` if you want to use modules for your application

```
requires java.sql;
```

If you do not want to use modules, delete the `module-info.java`

Comment: From the screenshot you can see that Java 9 or higher is used, otherwise there would be errors shown for the `module-info.java` file. Deleting the `module-info.java` file is also a solution for this issue when using Java 9 or higher since it's not mandatory to use JPMS.

Comment: This approach would make main code in /src/main/java unneccessarily depending on java.sql. In 2024, is there a better approach to resolve this Eclipse error (except making the project non-modular by deleting module-info.java)?

Comment: @user27772, the original question is "How to use `java.sql.*` classes in a modular project". If you do not have a dependency on `java.sql.*`, then remove the `requires java.sql;` from `module-info.java`.